# Packaging front end file of web application

Tags: javascript, build, frontend

I have developed front end using html and javascript files.Now I want create 3 different build of this for different environment like DEV,UAT and production.
Do we have any tool which packages files in this manner so we have different package for different environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a build tool like webpack or gulp to create different builds.

If you are using gulp you could minify your code only in production mode like in this example: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/gulp/minify-only-production

webpack example:
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The packaging part can be brilliantly handled using 'webpack'.
A good example for this can be found at the following link:

http://voidcanvas.com/setup-javascript-project-environment-with-webpack-eslint-babel-git/